# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed has no loadable segments

Tags: android, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am getting this error when installing/Debugging-->Launching the app in android studio

```
System.loadLibrary(LIB_NAME);
```

error msg:

```
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app-lib/xxx/libmylib.so" has no loadable segments
```

My lib folder:

```
$ tree
.
├── armeabi
│   ├── libmylib.so
│   └── libqp.so
└── x86
    └── libqp.so

2 directories, 3 files
```

Comment: In other applications, the so file is OK

Comment: same device other application with same so work well? can you show me the tree struct of your jniLibs folder.

Comment: yes! my folder like this : $ tree
.
├── armeabi
│   ├── libmylib.so
│   └── libqp.so
└── x86
    └── libqp.so

2 directories, 3 files

Comment: can you delete the x86 folder and try again? I had same problem in some phones.

Comment: I tried it , But still not work.

Comment: last one you can try, unzip the so from the two apk, and check md5, to make sure there are same. good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I use the same in other OS like Windows, it work perfect. but in the OSX, it still case exception.

Comment: ...but we are talking about Anroid. you means the emulator?

Comment: not emulator. I mean the IDE platform

Comment: so would try this i advised: `unzip the so from the two apk, and check md5, to make sure there are same`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I accidentally rename **name** to **lastName** in my project.
And the word **name** in .so file also renamed to **lastName**

For fast solution I just replace the original .so file to my project and it solved the issue.

Hope it help!